# Rails upgrade: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for assign_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have uprgaded from rails 3.2.12 to 4.0.0 most thinks working fine now, but I got this error:

[image]

Whats the Problem in this case?

Comment: try `send("assign_attributes", params[:user].merge(without_protection: true))`

Comment: This question is kinda out of the scope, but why use `#send` if you know that you are going to call `assign_attributes`, you coud just replace it with a normal `@user.assign_attributes(params[:user])` and then add `@user.without_protection = true`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message signature changed from two arguments to one. Compare [v3.2.12](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes) and [v4.0.2](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes):

```
assign_attributes(new_attributes, options = {}) # 3.2.12

assign_attributes(new_attributes)               # 4.0.2
```

Rails 3 mass assignment protection is deprecated, and this is part of it. Protecting attributes from mass assignment was [extracted into a gem](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes). From its README:

> You can also bypass mass-assignment security by using the `:without_protection` option.

In versions 4.x, you don't need the `:without_protection` option anymore because you're [encouraged to use Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html).

**For a smooth upgrade**, you can probably just bundle the `protected_attributes` gem. But note that "this plugin will be officially supported until the release of Rails 5.0."

Also, you don't need to use `@user.send(:update_attributes, …)`, you can just use `@user.update_attributes(…)`.